# Setting Customized Example for @ApiResponse

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am facing issue with example in response.

```
@ApiResponse(code=200,
    message="fetch list of Service/Config Resources",
    response = testing.class,
    responseContainer = "List",
    examples=@Example(
        value = @ExampleProperty(
            mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            value = "{testingId: 1234, testingName = Testing Name}"
        )
    )
)
```

But getting response example as

```
[
    {
        "testingId": "string",
        "testingName": "string"
    }
]
```

Comment: Also add which swagger version you are using?

Comment: `@ApiResponse(description = "boo",content = @Content(mediaType = "*/*",schema = @Schema(implementation = GenericError.class),examples = {@ExampleObject(name = "boo", value = "example",summary = "example of boo", externalValue = "example of external value")}))`

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding,
i am using swagger 2.0....Content , ExampleObject , Schema is not resolvable here.

Comment: then: you are *not* using swagger-annotations:2.0 ... [Content](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/2.0.0-rc0/io/swagger/oas/annotations/media/Content.html), [ExampleObject](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/2.0.0-rc0/io/swagger/oas/annotations/media/ExampleObject.html), [Schema](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/2.0.0-rc0/io/swagger/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html) ..looks rather like (at least) [1.6](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/1.6.0/index.html) ..please clarify your version.

Comment: using 2.0, i confirm